# Benefits of using [] over array() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, shorttags

I just found out about the short tags for arrays in PHP.

in my code I use :

```
$arr = array();
// do something
```

Now I can use :

```
$arr = []
```

So what's the benefit of using [] over array() in PHP?

Comment: Other than typing less characters? There is none. They both do the same thing. (Although you should note some very old PHP versions don't support the `[]` syntax.)

Comment: The short array syntaxe is avaliable since php5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no difference between `[]` and `array()`, these both declarations are literally called as array declarations itself. the benefit here is you save some time while typing `array`(5), while you can do it as `[]`(2).